# SQL statement about join

Tags: sql, oracle, join

Question: List the name of the staff member as 'staff_member' and the name of the supervisor as 'supervisor' for all staff members who do not live in the same city as their supervisor.

Relations:

```
Staff (Snum, Name, DOB, Address, City, Gender, Salary, Supervisor,Dnum) 
Dept ( Dnum, Dname, Manager, Mgrstartdate ) 
Deptlocation ( Dnum, Dcity ) 
Project ( Pnum, Pname, Pcity, Dnum ) 
Workson ( Snum, Pnum, Hours )

Column Supervisor of table Staff is a foreign key which references column Snum of table Staff.
Column Dnum of table Staff is a foreign key which references column Dnum of table Dept.
Column Manager of table Dept is a foreign key which references column Snum of table Staff.
Column Dnum of table Deptlocation is a foreign key which references column Dnum of table Dept.
Column Dnum of table Project is a foreign key which references column Dnum of table Dept.
Column Snum of table Workson is a foreign key which references column Snum of table Staff.
Column Pnum of table Workson is a foreign key which references column Pnum of table Project.
```

What I got so far:

```
SELECT name AS staff_member,  supervisor
from staff s
INNER JOIN deptlocation d ON s.dnum = d.dnum
WHERE s.city NOT EXISTS (d.city)
```

What am I doing wrong ?

```
Error:Your query has syntax errors.
Description:java.sql.SQLException: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
```

Comment: What column indicates the city where someone lives?

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: I would say in staff column city

Comment: update your question add  a clear data sample and the expected  result

Comment: Please clarify via edits, not comments. Read the documention/manual for features you are using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a `self join`.
I am considering that `supervisor` column in `staff` table points to `snum` of `supervisor` from `staff` table.

```
Select st.name as staff_member, 
       Sp.name as supervisor
  From staff st 
       Inner join staff sp 
       On (st.supervisor = sp.snum)
 Where st.city <> sp.city;
```

Cheers!!

Answer (score 0):

**try this:**

```
SELECT name AS staff_member,  supervisor
from staff s
INNER JOIN deptlocation d ON s.dnum = d.dnum
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
select 1 from deptlocation aa
aa.city=s.city 
)
```